# Thumbnail of video

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a thumbnail for video uploaded by user .
The video size is large and google suggested to use FFMPEG .

I dont know if FFMPEG library in LARAVEL is faster or executing ffmpeg command from code is faster ?? 
or ,speed isnot issue in both case of creating thumbnail  .

I googeled but i didnt get anything related to this .

So far i have created thumbnail using ffmpeg command

```
    $ffmpeg = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg';
    $image_file = 'uploads\\' .$name ."." ."png";
    $size = "120x90";
    $getfromsecond = 5;
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $file_video -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $image_file 2>&1";
```

and created by

```
  shell_exec($command);
```

I just want efficient way.
I am in laravel 5.1.

Comment: Running a command is always faster than using a wrapper for the same utility.

Comment: thanks for ur reply , cam i implement this in server without any problem ??

Comment: I just edited my anwer .. please give a look .

Comment: Yes you can go ahead with your solution

Comment: Just asking what is the drawback relative to command line ffmpeg if i use laravel FFMPEG library .. i am just asking of curosity ... thanks for ur help